# Airbags in aircraft - is that just a military thing?

Tags: safety, general-aviation, military

The [Bell OH-58D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_OH-58_Kiowa#OH-58D) (a military helicopter used by the USA) has an airbag to make life better in the event of a crash.

[image: AirBags]

I had never heard of such a thing in an aircraft before and I wondered if this unique to the Bell OH-58 and, if not, whether civilian light aircraft come with such an option ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Airbag seatbelts on planes are a "new" thing ([well, since about 2001 apparently](http://www.amsafe.com/products-services/general-aviation/seatbelt-airbags/)), but they're available on new-production aircraft and can be retrofitted to older General Aviation planes as well.

You can also find them on some airliners (typically in the exit rows where the next row is too far away to assume a proper brace position).

AmSafe (the folks who make a good percentage of the aviation-approved seatbelts) [has a nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZfPJG3LXxk) ([or two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FboAm9RqUXM)) on the subject of aviation airbags.

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane_airbags) is a list of commercial airlines which have airbags installed.

Comment: +1, I'd also add that very few military aircraft have them as well.  Generally speaking, we're strapped in pretty well.

Comment: @Farhan Interesting list.  I just noticed that some airlines only provide airbags for first class or business class passengers.  The ethics involved are questionable, at best.