# Why are there no parachutes to carry the aeroplanes in case of serious accidents?

Tags: emergency, parachute, emergency-services

Sometimes I wonder why the manufacturers do not design a big parachute to carry the aeroplanes when serious accidents occur. Perhaps the high cost is the reason?! But is it more expensive than a human life!?

Comment: See also: [Why are commercial flights not equipped with parachutes?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2186/why-are-commercial-flights-not-equipped-with-parachutes?rq=1)

Comment: See also: [Why don't commercial jet aircraft have a break-apart, parachute escape system?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9243/why-dont-commercial-jet-aircraft-have-a-break-apart-parachute-escape-system/11864#11864)

Comment: I think the question is about a gigantic parachute for the whole airplane, not just passengers, so it would be a duplicate to 11864, not 593. The answer Khalid is that the added weight would be significantly more costly and the parachute would never be used. I can only think of two (2) incidents in all of history in which it might have been used and in both cases the aircraft landed safely anyway.

Comment: Short answer: such systems would take more lives than they save. Remember, every dollar you add to the cost of air transportation means a few more people will travel by cars and thus a few more people will die in car accidents.