# Airframe parachute on commercial airlines

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, airframe-parachute

My question, would a multi-deployment airframe parachute system be viable on a commercial airline? For example, Grumman & Cirrus already use this system.

As with the automobile industries, they were found to be culpable of many road deaths prior to implementation of seatbelts (refused by all the automakers at the time), so is it the airlines' responsibility for not making flight safe enough when the technology is there to implement?

You cannot buy a new car without it having airbags, why not airframe parachute on every new plane as a standard?

Comment: What is a space frame parachute? Is it for the whole plane, chunks of the plane, or passengers? (we have questions already asked about all three: all are not cost-effective and would not be useful in the vast majority of fatal crashes, and cost-benefit analysis still applies when dealing with miniscule risks to life or else we'd have banned cars long ago, but I'm not sure if this question is a duplicate of [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2186/923), [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9564/923), or [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9243/923)).

Comment: @cpast after researching about Grumman & Cirrus, I'd say what he meant was "airframe parachute".

Comment: @AndrewT. Ah, makes sense.

Comment: @AndrewT. bur neither of those are commercial, are they? did he meant "civilian"?

Comment: @Federico I think he's saying "these non-commercial planes have it, why not commercial planes?" Also, since the comment didn't post, possible duplicate of [Why don't big commercial planes have full aircraft parachutes?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9564/923).

Comment: @cpast it did not post because you already linked the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cirrus builds very small planes that fly at a very low altitude and at very small speeds, hence the parachutes (CAPS) can be used.
2. General aviation aircraft are HUGE, BULKY and designed to fly at very high mach numbers. They are not designed to "withhold spin" as required by the CAPS.

Moreover, if this was possible, this would already be in action, because an Automobile accident is not much of a Headache for auto companies, but an Aviation disaster is for sure a PR nightmare for an Aviation Company.